# Why does my Docker composer not work with volume?

Tags: docker, windows, volume

I'm trying to create a volume to be shared among the containers, and this volume binds to a location of my host, the problem is that every time I run the docker-compose up gives the  following error:

```
In file '. \ docker-compose.yml', service 'volumes' must be a mapping not an array.
```

and so far I didn't understand why.  Following is the compose file:

```
version : '3.4'

services:
    testando-volume-compartilhado-a:
      image: carloshenriquecarniatto/teste:latest

    volumes:
       - D:\App:/app
    ports:
        - "10001:80"
        - "44378:443"
```

Comment: I have maked changes but not solved....

Answer (score 3):

It seems there is a spacing issue in your yaml

You should change the compose file to

```
version : '3.4'

services:
    testando-volume-compartilhado-a:
      image: carloshenriquecarniatto/teste:latest

    volumes:        
        - D:\App:/app  # <- extra space here
    ports:
        - "10001:80"
        - "44378:443"
```

Comment: The examples in [Compose file version 3 reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) seem to suggest that the hyphen is actually correct, i.e. it **should* be a YAML list.  It's possible here that the additional `:` in the Windows path is confusing the YAML parser? I know little to nothing about Docker Compose.  Equally, it might be that the [indentation is off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39555650/error-in-file-docker-compose-yml-service-volumes-must-be-a-mapping-not-a), as in the D of volumes is indented by three, ports by four and image by two.

Comment: you're quite right @RichardSlater

Answer (score 0):

It is a spacing issue, but because of indentation.

`volumes` and `ports` should be at the same level of image

```
version : '3.4'
```

services:
testando-volume-compartilhado-a:
image: carloshenriquecarniatto/teste:latest

```
  volumes:
     - D:\App:/app
  ports:
      - "10001:80"
      - "44378:443"
```

I am not sure about the Windows volume mapping (Linux only here)...but the indentation was off for sure!